# Teradata - calculating age 20+ customers

Tags: date, datetime, teradata

supposed my database has the following structure
each row is a sale order and there could be duplicated customer.id

columns: customer.id, birthdate, eye.color

how would i write the select query for the total number of distinct customers who are age 20+ and group by eye.color in (1,2,3)?

Thanks!

Comment: Age 20+ = `where birthdate <= add_months(current_date, -12*20)` plus `count(distinct`...)

Comment: sorry, a little edit. i'm looking help for the query!

Comment: What's your current query? This is a very basic SQL task...

Comment: @kizunairo https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask